# Mathematica integral evaluation just shows up as nicely formatted text?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Attempting the following exponential integral:

```
Integrate[  Exp[-2 A Sqrt[x^2 + a^2] + I ( x Subscript[k, x] + b )],
            {x, 0,   Infinity}
]
```

I get back something that is pretty printed, but not evaluated?  Does this mean that Mathematica could not perform the integral and gave up?  I don't see any messages saying that's what happened.

To provide context for this question, this is a stripped down to one dimension version of the integral I'd done with paper and pencil:

```
\int d^3 r e^{ i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} } e^{ - 2 Z r/ a_0 }
```

The point of trying mathematica was to see if I could verify my result:

```
16 \pi Z a_0^3/(4 Z^2 + k^2 a_0^2)^2
```

Comment: Even the simpler integral of `Exp[-2 Sqrt[x^2 + a^2]]` is not performed by Mathematica. Do you know of a closed form / special function representation of this integral (definite or indefinite)?

Comment: @Simon the result for this one is `a BesselK[1, 2 a]`, You can get it via substitutions `x->a*Tan[y], y->ArcCos[t], t->1/p` (perhaps there is an easier way, my integration skills are a bit rusty now). What you get is `a*Integrate[Exp[-2 a p]*p/Sqrt[p^2-1],{p,1,Infinity}]`, which results in a Bessel. *EDIT* Oops, did not see the answer by Peter. Will leave this comment anyway.

Comment: @Leonid: I didn't even attempt to integrate it, I was merely pointing out that the OP had not done due diligence and reduced the question to its core problem (although he wasn't actually asking what the integral was, rather just about the behaviour of Mma). Frankly, I was surprised that Mma and [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-2+Sqrt%5Bx^2+%2B+a^2%5D%5D%2C+{x%2C+0%2C+Infinity}%5D) could not do the integral and I should have tried some transformations and beaten you and Peter Pein to the answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, when Mathematica spits the integral back out it usually means it doesn't know how to do it. Sometimes, it can only do the integral under certain assumptions (such as `a > 0' and real), but it will usually give the answer as a gigantic if-statement with those.

This particular integral you have is not trivial at all. And it doesn't fit the form of any of the special functions that I'm familiar with. So it's possible that it can't be expressed in closed form in terms of the special functions that Mathematica has.

Also, what's the point of the `Subscript[k, x]`? I tried removing it and Mathematica still can't do the integral.

Comment: k_x was meant to be a constant (like a, b, and A).

Answer (score 7):

With a simple change of variables the 'simple' case `Exp[-2 A Sqrt[a^2 + x^2]` yields besselfunctions:

```
Integrate[Exp[-2*A*Sqrt[a^2 + x^2]]*Dt[x] /. x -> Sqrt[t^2 - a^2] /. Dt -> (1 & ), {t, a, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 0 < A]
```

to get

```
a*(-BesselK[0, 2*a*A] + BesselK[1, 2*a*A])
```